# Checking on execute boolean or using try/catch PDO

Tags: javascript, pdo

I'm sorry for my bad title. I use a lot of AJAX for my project and in the AJAX I mostly return either 'error' or 'success' and the message in an array. In Javascript I print the message in a custom notification bar.

Now, I am not pretty sure what's the default way of giving an error. I need to check on my PDO query for success or failure for the return array. I don't know whether to check on the `execute()` boolean or I should use a try/catch.

Is there a big difference for error handling.

Comment: Try catch is used to catch an exception and to write particular behavior if an exception occurred.

Comment: That mainly depends on whether you have set PDO to exception error mode or not.

Comment: Error mode is on exception.

Comment: If it can throw an `Exception` then you use `try/catch`. Since a connection can always break unexpectedly, you also check for the return value of `->execute()`. If everything went as expected, you return `json_encoded` array with information and http status code 200. If something went wrong, you log it somewhere on the server (syslog, log file) so it's not printed on user's screen and you return an according http status code along with optionally `json_encoded` array that carries some sort of a message. That's how I would do it, your approach can differ but always check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a difference in this case, but I'd check for `PDOStatement->execute()`.

There is a case when you're updating/deleting some rows and your `PDOStatement->execute()` will return true even if no rows satisfied the `where` conditions, thats because no exception happened. In that case, you should use `PDOStatement->rowCount()` to know how many rows were affected.

Observation: don't rely on [PDOStatement->rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) for select statements as:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications

Comment: Yeah didn't really think of `rowCount()`, but I think it'd be a good idea to implement it too. Thanks for the answer!